# Letsencrypt apache Multilevel subdomain not working with https

Tags: apache, https, subdomain

I finally got letsencrypt working with on my V-Server and redirection of my subdomains.

Now I have the problem, that http_s://sub1.example.com works fine, but if I have a multi level subdomain like http_s://sub2.sub1.example.com it doesn`t work and I get no response. If I use http://sub2.sub1.example.com, it works.

Does anybody has an idea, how can I support multi level subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a certificate valid for that sub domain.

You can :

- Generate one certificate valid for sub1.example.com and another certificate for sub2.sub1.example.com
- Generate one certificate valid for sub1.example.com and sub2.sub1.example.com

The fact that it's a sub sub domain is irrelevant here.

Comment: OK. But why does sub1.example.com works without doing anything with https, but sub2.sub1.example.not not?

Comment: What you mean "doesnt work"? You need to be more specific to get an answer, a lot of things can go wrong :)

Comment: And ssllabs.com is often useful to answer that question.

Comment: Sorry, with http_s://sub2.sub1.example.com I get ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT. If I type htt_p://sub2.sub1.example.com, I`m getting redirected without SSL. If I type either htt_p/http_s://sub1.example.com I`m getting redirected.

Comment: What does ssllabs.com says about the subdomain sub2.sub1.example.com ?

Comment: Solved it by using minus character instead of multilevel domains with dots.